# What's the best way to handle List or Dictionaries within Objects in C#

Tags: c#, oop

I often create objects which contain lists or dictionaries

What's the ideal way of handling this?

For Example:

```
class Person
{
    public List<person> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

But this means I need to verify that Friends is initialized prior to adding items to it.  So I sometimes go with:

```
class Person
{
    public List<Person> Friends = new List<Person>();
}
```

But that's obviously not ideal either because it's a public field.

I could initialize in the constructor or I could probably go with lazy instantiation too:

```
class Person
{
    private List<Person> friends;

    public List<Person> Friends
    {
        get 
        {
            if (friends == null)
                friends = new List<Person>();
            return friends; 
        }
        set { friends = value; }
    }

}
```

But that's really verbose.  No option seems really good in any case.

Comment: Why does option 2 seem bad?  What does it being public have to do with anything?

Comment: My understanding was that public fields are normally discouraged.

Comment: @Mason11987: You can make it a public property and initialize it in the constructor.  Though there are more questions to ask.  For example, consumers of a public `IList<>` can modify the collection itself, and elements within the collection, without the object knowing.  Is that the behavior you're looking for?

Comment: @Mason11987 you are right - I didn't catch that you changed it from a _property_ to a _field_.

Comment: " Is that the behavior you're looking for?"

I'd say so.  If that was an issue though, what alternatives would I have?  Would I then want to make the list private and only expose my own public add/retrieve methods for the list?

Comment: @Mason11987: That's an option.  Ultimately it comes down to how the object itself should behave and what it should expose.  Maybe a public property which returns a `ReadOnlyCollection` and expose add/remove methods on the object?  Maybe return an `IEnumerable` instead of an `IList`?  It depends on what the object should expose.

Comment: @David is right. Its not great practice to expose the List<> for modification by other objects. The Person object should be the sole proprietor to how that List is handled. In your example the Person is an Anemic Domain Model - which goes against the SOLID and OOP principles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a good pratice, you can use a property with a `private set` and initialize on the `constructor` (where is the place to do this, since you create a `Person` object), for sample:

```
public class Person
{
    public List<Person> Friends { get; private set; }

    public Person() 
    {
       this.Friends = new List<Person>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I (and I'm guessing most people as well) would initialize it in the constructor.
Lazy initialization is only worth the trouble if the resource is expensive to create and you can't be sure whether you'll even need it.

For lists and dictionaries: just initialize them in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If the added memory overhead isn't an issue for you (and it most likely isn't, unless you're dealing with millions of objects), the best practice is probably to skip the lazy initialization, mark the field `readonly`, and initialize it inline:

```
class Person
{
    private readonly List<Person> friends = new List<Person>();

    public List<Person> Friends
    {
        get { return friends; }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, the initializer can be moved into the constructor.  It makes no real difference in this case; it's a stylistic decision.

There also doesn't seem to be a compelling need to allow the list itself to be replaced by external code, so just make the property read-only by omitting the `set` accessor.

@FelipeOriani's suggestion is very close to mine, and is a perfectly acceptable alternative.  I personally prefer to enforce `readonly` semantics for fields whenever appropriate (particularly for collections), ensuring they can only be initialized during object creation, but this mostly a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try to use [Lazy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) construct available from  `4.0` version

So your code may look like:

```
class Person
{
    private Lazy<List<Person>> friends = new Lazy<List<Person>>();
    public Lazy<List<Person>> Friends {
         get { return friends; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ha, that's pretty interesting.  Haven't seen Lazy Before.  I could see how that might be useful in some situations.

Comment: It's the same as you did it in your code, but with shorter and cleaner syntax as it's built-in language construct.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
class Person
{
    private List<Person> friends;

    public List<Person> Friends
    {
        get { return friends ?? (friends = new List<Person>()); }
        set { friends = value; }
    }

}
```

?

Comment: First I've seen of ??.  Not sure if I'd use it in this context, but thanks for introducing it to me!

Comment: @Mason11987 I would probably use the constructor too. However I posted this answer because it's the closest one to your question: it does exactly the same thing as your code example **but without** being verbose.